# How to copy parent node based on child node's condition using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I am working on transforming the following xml.

```
<root>

<node1>
  <node2 id="1">xyz</node2>
</node1>

<node1>
  <node2 id="2">abc</node2>
</node1>

<parent>
 <child>abc</child>
</parent>

</root>
```

I want to transform it to the following format:

```
<root>

<node1>
  <node2 id="1">xyz</node2>
</node1>

<parent>
 <child>abc</child>

 <node1>
  <node2 id="2">abc</node2>
 </node1>

</parent>

</root>
```

- I am using identity template to copy all the elements
- I have added the template to copy child element

I need to check id attribute and if it is equal to 2, then copy the parent node. I would be grateful if anyone help in this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input XML's format is not deviating much from as in your question, this XSLT will work:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*/*[*[@id = '2']]"/>

<xsl:template match="parent">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="/*/*[*[@id = '2']]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```